# Foreign-Referencing a composite Key that has individual columns that cannot be unique

Tags: mysql

I am new in SQL and was creating tables in MySQL and faced with the following error:

[source path\create_bookAuthor_table.sql
ERROR: 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'book_author_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'author'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBOf.png)

I have an Author table with a M-N relationship with a Book table where one author can Author many books, and one book can be authored by many authors.

So, I need to create a junction table called BookAuthor that actually can show the books an author has authored, or rather the authors per book.

I cannot make the first name and last name to be unique as many people can share one name.

I was wondering how do I enforce the foreign key with that in mind?

My code for Book looks as follows:

```
create table book (
  isbn varchar(20) not null,
  '
  '
  '
  primary key(isbn),
  
);
```

For Author:

```
create table author (
  first_name varchar(20) not null, 
  last_name varchar(20) not null, 
  primary key(last_name, first_name)
);
```

For BookAuthor that throws the error:

```
create table book_author (
  isbn varchar(20) not null,
  first_name varchar(20) not null, 
  last_name varchar(20) not null, 
  primary key(isbn, first_name, last_name),
  foreign key(first_name, last_name) references author(first_name, last_name),
  foreign key(isbn) references book(isbn)
);
```

Comment: Side note: First name and last name might not good be good keys. In the real world there might be more than one author with the same names.

Comment: I agree with you on that. Tom mentioned that below and I will put it into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key in the author table is `last_name, first_name`, in the foreign key in the book_author table it is `first_name, last_name`.

Comment: would the order in which they are listed matter, really? I tried interchanging them and the error persists. Also note that the error mentions  that the issue is with a missing index.

Comment: I got an error when trying your create statement until I swapped them then I got no error.

Comment: @DavidM: To be a little more precise: First and last name are swapped in the `REFERENCES` clause. That is the actual problem. You could leave the foreign key as `(first_name, last_name)` but use `REFERENCES author (last_name, first_name)` and it wouldn't throw an error because both columns are `varchar(20)`. But of course that would also force you to swap the meaning of the columns which would then make a change of their names useful and you'd end up with `(last_name, first_name) REFERENCES author (last_name, first_name)` again.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the issue was the order of first and last names. As much as it could seem trivial, it was indeed consequential. it works now! Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, please mark the answer ticked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary keys should not be meaningful data imho (it always leads to tears).

Link with integers would be my recommendation.

Comment: I agree. An artificial int key might do a better job